# Not able to extract Instagram account data connected to Facebook page using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to access the media of my Instagram business account connected to Facebook page through Facebook Graph API.

I've set up everything as requested: I have an Instagram business account, a Facebook page connected to this account and a Facebook app.

When I try to get the Instagram Account ID with

```
GET /v3.3/{page id}?fields=instagram_business_account
```

the response I get looks different than the one in the guide. The Instagram business account field is missing, I only get back the ID of the Facebook page, which I already have.

Please suggest is it required to submit Instagram permission

#### instagram_basic

#### instagram_manage_insights

for review to get Instagram account media data for an **admin user**?

Note :-I can't change my Instagram account to private and then to business again.Because i can't lose my insights.

I expect the output with a business_instagram_id but the actual result return the page id itself.
Please suggest.

Comment: The access token you use for the request needs to be a page access token with at least the instagram_basic permission.

Comment: yeah ,but using page access token ,i'm receiving only page id itself in return.
or are you saying to submit instagram_basic permission for review?
For now i'm trying by providing permissions in beta version of graph-api.

Comment: You don't need the permission to be reviewed as long as you are the admin of the app and the page. Please check the access token and the contained permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: well i have checked it .Token have instagram_basic and manage_pages permission.But still i'm not able to get business_id.@Norbert

Comment: Hello. Did you solve it ? I have the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001632/ig-account-is-linked-to-fb-page-but-page-idfields-instagram-business-account-no

Answer (score 0):

Add extra permission in auth request: `pages_read_engagement`