# IG account is linked to FB page but PAGE_ID?fields=instagram_business_account not returning the IG account ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

My instagram account is connected to my Facebook page but when I want to see the Instagram business account with :

```
FB_PAGE_OD?fields=instagram_business_account
```

I don't receive the IG account ID, only the FB page ID :

```
{
  "id": "FB_PAGE_ID"
}
```

instead of :

```
{
  "instagram_business_account": {
    "id": "IG_ID"
  },
  "id": "FB_PAGE_ID"
}
```

I have another facebook page, connected to another IG account, and it works. (app is the same, permissions are the same :

```
pages_show_list
business_management
instagram_basic
instagram_content_publish
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
```

so this is not a permission issue.

And when I want to publish something on the IG, I got :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"AH_kGKvbEgNsDWgGaKt2-Vf"}}
```

(but I can publish on the Facebook page)

Any ideas?

(and yes, I have disconnected / reconnected the IG account to the FB page many times already)

And on the Meta Business Suite I can see that the Facebook page and the Instagram profile are correctly linked.

It seems that I'm not the only one with this issue :

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/147095285045879/

Thanks

Comment: did you have a solution for this? recently, they release Business Login for Instagram. I wonder if it's related to this.